# Dotvvm multiselect business pack filtering backspace doesn't work

Tags: multi-select, dotvvm

I Used component from Business pack called MultiSelect viz code:

```
<bp:MultiSelect DataSource="{value: UserRoleGroupNames}" SelectedValues="{value: UserDetailDTO.UserRoleGroupNames}" Placeholder="Vyberte uživatelské role" class="form-control"/>
```

Everything looks good expect filtering. I cant delete letters with backspace key.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you! I've been able to repro this issue. It will be fixed in next release.